# guava: Transform a list to a map with the index as the key

Tags: java, collections, guava

In my app I have a List names. I wish to convert this to a map based on the index value. For example

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
names.add("Pratik");
names.add("Pratik");
names.add("Ram");
names.add("Varun");
```

Can you help me with some guava/java api method which can help me get a map where the key is the index and value is name even if there are duplicate values? SO if there are two "Pratik" String in names. The map should be like this

> 0 -> "Pratik", 1->"Pratik",2->"Ram",3->"Varun"

Comment: Why do you need that? You'd use it exactly the same way as a List... You would only have quite some overhead for the map... I only see cons, and no pros for this approach.

Comment: And why don't you simply loop and construct the map. It's only 2 lines of code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you don't need Guava here:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
int i = 0;
for (String name : names) {
    map.put(i++, name);
}

System.out.println(map);
```

prints:

```
{0=Pratik, 1=Pratik, 2=Ram, 3=Varun}
```

If you absolutely want a way to do it with Guava, you could do this (but I would recommend the JDK way to avoid unnecessary complexity):

```
Maps.asMap(
     ContiguousSet.create(Range.closedOpen(0, names.size()), DiscreteDomain.integers()),
          new Function<Integer, String>() {
              @Override
              public String apply(Integer input) {
                  return names.get(input);
              }
          });
```

By the way, I don't see why you would have to do this.